# How to upgrade kafka_2.10 0.8.1.1 to Kafka client 0.9 library

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We try to upgrade **kafka_2.10 0.8.1.1** to **kafka-clients 0.9.0.0**, and found a lot of classes were changed ,and some class were not founded

> MessageAndMetadata,KafkaStream
>
> TopicFilter,Blacklist
>
> .....

Does anybody know if we use wrong kafka java client library or these class was changed ??